# How to use composite index in below scenario

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, composite

I have a table `ABC` with columns `X`, `Y`, `Z` and an index `idx1` on `(X,Y)`.

How to modify the below query so that index will be used.

```
select * from ABC where Y = 'TEST';
```

I tried in this way. But it is not working.

```
select /*+ index(ABC idx1) */ * from ABC where Y = 'TEST';
```

Answer (score 1):

The index on (X,Y) cannot be used to **seek** for specific values of Y.

Think about a phone book directory, similar to white pages.
It is indexed (sorted) by (Last Name, First Name).

How would you use this directory to search for all people with the first name (Bob)?
The only way is to **scan** the entire index row by row.

However, If you need to search for (Smith, Bob) you can easily seek the Smith pages, and then within these quickly find all your Bobs by the alphabetical order.

If you need to search for Y values only, you will need an index that has Y as the first key.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You said your index is related to 2 columns, `X` and `Y`.

But your `WHERE` clause only relates to the `Y` column, hence the index is not used, even if you use a hint.

Either :

- change the `WHERE` clause to filter on both `X` and `Y` columns
- OR create an index on column `Y` only

The correct solution depends on your functional use case. In both case you won't need the hint.